# `/var` is full and mounted on a separate partition

Tags: partitioning, debian

During the installation of Debian, accidentally I separated `/var` from root. Here is my `df -h` command output:

```
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                        3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                       781M   81M  701M  11% /run
/dev/mapper/vg_system-root   44G   17G   25G  41% /
tmpfs                       3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       5.0M   12K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/mapper/vg_system-home  179G  151G   20G  89% /home
/dev/sda1                   455M  168M  263M  39% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_system-var   5.1G  5.1G     0 100% /var
/dev/loop0                  128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop2                   56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2785
/dev/loop1                   56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2751
/dev/loop3                   74M   74M     0 100% /snap/core22/817
/dev/loop4                   74M   74M     0 100% /snap/core22/858
/dev/loop5                   48M   48M     0 100% /snap/cumulonimbus/83
/dev/loop6                   97M   97M     0 100% /snap/freetube-snap/55
/dev/loop7                   97M   97M     0 100% /snap/freetube-snap/63
/dev/loop8                  486M  486M     0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/120
/dev/loop9                   92M   92M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop10                 113M  113M     0 100% /snap/julia/80
/dev/loop11                 113M  113M     0 100% /snap/julia/83
/dev/loop13                 449M  449M     0 100% /snap/kf5-5-106-qt-5-15-9-core22/23
/dev/loop12                 237M  237M     0 100% /snap/kasts/6
/dev/loop14                  20M   20M     0 100% /snap/nvim/2791
/dev/loop15                  23M   23M     0 100% /snap/nvim/2810
/dev/loop17                  54M   54M     0 100% /snap/snapd/19361
/dev/loop18                  94M   94M     0 100% /snap/youtube-dl/4806
/dev/loop16                  54M   54M     0 100% /snap/snapd/19457
tmpfs                       781M  144K  781M   1% /run/user/1000
```

You see the var is full, and my machine does not work properly. How can I resolve this? Should I resize `/var` or put it into root?

Comment: Is it OK to copy its content into root and remove it from `fstab`?

Comment: What is the result of `vgs`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov `

  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree 
  vg_system   1   4   0 wz--n- <238.00g <5.21g

Comment: First add this to question, not comment. Second, you have 5GB free, so (temporary) you can resolve the issue

Comment: WHat is the filesystem of `/var`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have some free space in LVM you can extend the `/var` filesystem with command:

```
lvresize -L+1G -r /dev/mapper/vg_system-var
```

The key `-r` with resize also the filesystem for you.

As next steps login, cleanup `/var`. And if you want to have more free space in VG you can shrink (eventually) `/home`